# get property from different ant project

Tags: ant

Is it possible to read properties **from** another ant project ?

I could do it with:

```
<ant antfile="child/build.xml" target="echoproperties">
  <property name="echoproperties.file" value="${tmp}/child.properties" />
</ant>
<property prefix="child" file="${tmp}/child.properties" />
<delete file="${tmp}/child.properties" />
```

While in `child/build.xml`:

```
<target name="echoproperties">
  <echoproperties destfile="${echoproperties.file}" />
</target>
```

But I would like to avoid creating temporary files.

Comment: There is an "inheritAll" attribute on the ant task, which passes the parent build's properities. The other options is one or more "property" tags as in your example above.

Comment: You misunderstood - I need to get property out of another project (from child to parent), not share it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that Ant-Contrib has [antfetch](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/antfetch_task.html) task although it's functionality is not that great (no prefix, no propertysets).